# How to prevent C# class instance implicit conversion to class name

Tags: c#, string, casting, instance, implicit

I'm surprised to see that

```
using System;


namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Potato
    {
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Potato potato = new Potato();

            string result = "Hi there, " + potato;

            Console.Write(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

not only compiles, but produces the result

> Hi there, ConsoleApp.Potato

Is there no way to prevent this implicit cast? Producing compiler error as default behavior would be ideal, in my opinion.

(Running Visual Studio, with .NET Framework 4.5, C# version should be 5.0. Also see it happening on 4.6.1 (C# 6.0))

Comment: You can't because there exists [`String.Concat(object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-5.0#System_String_Concat_System_Object_) which is what the compiler will call for concatenating a string with any kind of object. This is how the language is defined. Incidentally, there is no casting going on here.

Comment: The default behaviour of C# language is that `"Hi there, " + potato` is turned into `"Hi there, " + potato.ToString()`, which by defaults returns the name of the type.

Comment: overriding the tostring method should do the trick `public override string ToString()
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("INVALID CAST");
        }` but its not a cast anyway.

Comment: @TinoZ I agree this might be the only way to produce the behavior the OP wants but I still would not recommend doing this. Noone will expect an `InvalidCastException` in a `ToString()`. Loggers and so on may also call `ToString`.

Comment: It's the first time this behavior actually caused a tricky bug for me. I always use very explicit code, so I may have been protected from these cases. Never too late to learn, I guess (I was a C# programmer for many years, and had to come back after a few years intermission).

Comment: @Dominik you are right, A logger CAN, so the OP has to take care of that, it's his choice and HIS requirement :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no "implicit cast" here. You are performing a string concatenation, which means that the [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring) method is called on everything that's not a string. And by default, `ToString()` on an object returns its type name.

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is that the `+` operator has an overload that accepts `object`. These are all the overloads:

```
string operator +(string x, string y);
string operator +(string x, object y);
string operator +(object x, string y);
```

You can pass almost anything to an `object` parameter.

And what happens when you call one of the overloads that accept `object`? Well, the [language sepc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#addition-operator) says:

> Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual `ToString` method inherited from type `object`.

You can't "disable" this and produce an error instead, because these overloads are mandated by the language spec, so every C# compiler would need to support them. You can try writing your own compiler that doesn't support them, but I don't recommend that.

You can, however, change it to something other than the class name by overriding `ToString` in your class:

```
public override string ToString() => "some string";
```